# converting json string with Gson for generic model

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

i have class like this

```
public class Response<T>{
   T item;
   List<T>;
}
```

so how can to deserializeding String in this pattern to one generic class with`gson.fromJson(targetString,...)`?

i glad to used in retrofit library where `Response` is returned parameter in desired interface

Answer (score 0):

convert list to gson

```
public <T> String setList(List<T> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(list);  
}
```

convert gson to list

```
public List<(desired class)> getList(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = (pass json string);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<(desired class)>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Add gson dependency to the app gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```